# Kubuntu won't log in, stuck on login splash screen

Tags: login

I am running Kubuntu 13.10. Out of the blue, I am now unable to log in. I rebooted, (only changed the desktop background, didn't update any packages or anything) and was taken to the login splash screen as usual because I have automatic login enabled. However, the loading bar I set as the splash is stuck on this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/db5PV.jpg (sorry, all I've got is this iPod.)

I tried restarting `lightdm`, and rebooting too, but those did nothing... It wouldn't be the graphics drivers, since I didn't mess around with them... How would I remedy this and get to a desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by purging the `kwin-effect-snow` package which I had installed.